# How to force a PHP variable to be a string?

Tags: php, jquery, sqlite, laravel, query-builder

## Global context

I'm using a the [Laravel's query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) and a SQLite database. Of course datetime type doesn't exist with SQLite and I use strftime to convert my timestamp to month or year value.

## The subtleties with SQlite I just discover

The following query works (tested directly with the SQLite Manager):

```
SELECT * FROM "articles" 
WHERE strftime("%Y", mydate, "unixepoch", "localtime") = "2013"
```

This one doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM "articles" 
WHERE strftime("%Y", mydate, "unixepoch", "localtime") = 2013
```

As far as I understand the comparison must be done with strings.

## The problem

How to resolve it with Laravel's query builder?

I've read that for DB's specific function I have to use `DB::raw` tool.

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
->where(DB::raw('strftime("%Y", articles.date,  "unixepoch", "localtime") '), $annee)
->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->toSql();
```

But the problem is the parameter `$annee` which is interpreted like a number when building the query.

I know there is no cast in PHP, and the interpretation depends of the context. Is there a way to influence the interpretation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but have you tried `(string) $annee` at the position you have now `$annee`? (Yes there is casting in PHP, but only to `string`, `array`, `float`, `int` and `object`)

Comment: @PetervanderWal `(string) $annee` works fine, thanks! When I've read the PHP manual I think I'd misunderstand the first line : `PHP does not support explicit type definition`.

Comment: That line means that a variable itself isn't being typed, like in Java, C# and other languages where you define a variable of a specific type (`string myVar`). In PHP `$myVar` can be a int on the first line, and hold a string on the next line. However the *value* stored in a variable is of a specific type, and you can change that type (called `Type Juggling` in PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type casting is supported in PHP, but only to string, array, float, int and object.

```
DB::table('articles')
->where( 'myColumn', (string) $annee)
->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->toSql();
```

But a quick and dirty way to do it is simply add a string to it.

```
DB::table('articles')
->where('myColumn', "" + $annee)
->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->toSql();
```

Comment: `+`? Do you mean `.`?

Answer (score 1):

Type casting is [absolutely supported in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

But a quick and dirty way to do it is simply add a string to it.

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
->where(DB::raw('strftime("%Y", articles.date,  "unixepoch", "localtime") '), "" + $annee)
->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->toSql();
```